# scale spring-kafka consumers app horizontally

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm wondering what would be a good approach to configure the amount of partitions in relation to the max number of horizontally scaled instances.

Suppose I have one topic with *6* partitions.

I have one application that uses the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` with `setConcurrency` of *6*.
That would mean I have will have *6* `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` each using one thread and consuming messages from all of my partitions spread out evenly.

If the above is correct then I was wondering what would happen if I scale the app horizontally by adding another instance ?
If the new instance would have the same configuration of a concurrency of 6 and ofcourse the same consumer group I believe the 2nd instance will not be consuming any messages. Because no rebalance will happen because each existing consumer will have one partition assigned to it.

But what if we go back to the first example and have *6* partition with one instance having a concurrency of 3 then each consumer thread/`KafkaMessageListenerContainer` will have *2* partitions assigned.
If we scale this app (same consumer group id and also a concurrency of 3) I believe that a rebalance will happen and both instances will individually be consuming from 3 partitions.

Are these assumptions correct and if not how should you handle such a case ?

Answer (score 2):

In general your assumption is correct for a default behavior, which is based on the:

```
/**
 * <p>The range assignor works on a per-topic basis. For each topic, we lay out the available partitions in numeric order
 * and the consumers in lexicographic order. We then divide the number of partitions by the total number of
 * consumers to determine the number of partitions to assign to each consumer. If it does not evenly
 * divide, then the first few consumers will have one extra partition.
 *
 * <p>For example, suppose there are two consumers <code>C0</code> and <code>C1</code>, two topics <code>t0</code> and
 * <code>t1</code>, and each topic has 3 partitions, resulting in partitions <code>t0p0</code>, <code>t0p1</code>,
 * <code>t0p2</code>, <code>t1p0</code>, <code>t1p1</code>, and <code>t1p2</code>.
 *
 * <p>The assignment will be:
 * <ul>
 * <li><code>C0: [t0p0, t0p1, t1p0, t1p1]</code></li>
 * <li><code>C1: [t0p2, t1p2]</code></li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * Since the introduction of static membership, we could leverage <code>group.instance.id</code> to make the assignment behavior more sticky.
 * For the above example, after one rolling bounce, group coordinator will attempt to assign new <code>member.id</code> towards consumers,
 * for example <code>C0</code> -&gt; <code>C3</code> <code>C1</code> -&gt; <code>C2</code>.
 *
 * <p>The assignment could be completely shuffled to:
 * <ul>
 * <li><code>C3 (was C0): [t0p2, t1p2] (before was [t0p0, t0p1, t1p0, t1p1])</code>
 * <li><code>C2 (was C1): [t0p0, t0p1, t1p0, t1p1] (before was [t0p2, t1p2])</code>
 * </ul>
 *
 * The assignment change was caused by the change of <code>member.id</code> relative order, and
 * can be avoided by setting the group.instance.id.
 * Consumers will have individual instance ids <code>I1</code>, <code>I2</code>. As long as
 * 1. Number of members remain the same across generation
 * 2. Static members' identities persist across generation
 * 3. Subscription pattern doesn't change for any member
 *
 * <p>The assignment will always be:
 * <ul>
 * <li><code>I0: [t0p0, t0p1, t1p0, t1p1]</code>
 * <li><code>I1: [t0p2, t1p2]</code>
 * </ul>
 */
public class RangeAssignor extends AbstractPartitionAssignor {
```

However you can plug in any `ConsumerPartitionAssignor` via `partition.assignment.strategy` consumer property: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_partition.assignment.strategy

See also `ConsumerPartitionAssignor` JavaDocs for more info and its implementations to make a choice for your use-case.

Comment: `>I believe the 2nd instance will not be consuming any messages` - it's not as simple as that; a rebalance occurs and the partitions will be distributed across any 6 of the 12 consumers, the other 6 will be idle. In general, you should over-provision to the number of partitions. Say you set it to 18; that will support 1 to 3 instances; in the first case, each consumer will get 3 partitions. It gets more complicated if you consume from multiple topics and they have different partition counts, or the total concurrency is > the number of partitions in one topic.

Comment: See See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#using-ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer